# Available on vs. available in

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Consider the following sentence:

"...both of these options are available in the betting app."

Is it correct to use "in" or "on" would be better? As in:

"...both of these options are available on the betting app."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would choose "in".

This is one of those weird English context-dependent things, where people will understand both ways.

The analogy that helps me is to think about a street, and a shop on the street. The shop is "on" the street, not "in" it. And items are "in" the shop, not "on" them.

So if *options* are a *part* of the betting app, then they're *in* the app. And your app is *on* the app-store, in the same way that a shop is *on* the street.